# C++ Interface, What's the best way to not duplicate code

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, interface, architecture

I have this problem:

I have an Event Manager that call the event function do()

```
Event *p; 
//p takes it values from an Event Queue
p->do()
```

Some Events have two attributes Object a and b

```
class EventX : public Event {

   public : 
       EventX();
       void do(){actionX(a, b)}
   private : 
       Object a;
       Object b;
       bool bothSide;

};

class EventY : public Event {

   public : 
       EventY();
       void do(){actionY(a,b);}
   private : 
       Object a;
       Object b;
       bool bothSide;

};
```

do() is a function that carries out an action from a to b.
I want to create an interface that can call do() from a to b and do() from b to a if bothSide attribute is true.
Is that possible ? I have many Event with differents do() functions that perform different actions from a to b.

Thank you for reading

Comment: if `do` is a virtual method in `Event` then the derived classes can implement it to do what ever they like. The question is unclear. Can you show the code you would like to write, but dont know how? Or show the code that you would like to avoid for duplication.

Comment: I clearly want to do make 
do(){
    if(bothSide)
          actionX(b, a)
    actionX(a, b)
}

Comment: You can write a template class based on some configuration parameter (here it is a boolean) and simply use the `constexpr` boolean to determine which action to perform. Or instead the parameter is some function/lambda that the class calls.

Comment: Since you haven't specified a criterion for "better", it's impossible to say what is best - at most, such a description is opinion-based, and different people have different opinions.   One *option* would be to place the members `a`, `b`, and `bothSide` and also declare a virtual function `do()`  in a common base class of both `EventX` and `EventY`.   That common base might be `Event` or another intermediate class derived from `Event`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have extra layer with another interface

```cpp
struct EventAB : Event
{
    void do() final { if (bothSide) action(b, a); action(a, b); }
    virtual void action(Object&, Object&) = 0;

/*...*/

private:
    Object a;
    Object b;
    bool bothSide = false;
};
```

And then

```cpp
class EventX : public EventAB {
public:
    void action(Object& lhs, Object& rhs) override { actionX(lhs, rhs); }
    // ...
};

class EventY : public EventAB {
public:
    void action(Object& lhs, Object& rhs) override { actionY(lhs, rhs); }
    // ...
};
```