# Does base class destructor need to be virtual if only some derived classes are polymorphic?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a similar situation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70376693/c-interface-whats-the-best-way-to-not-duplicate-code) where I have 2 classes that share a public interface function, and so I've pulled that function (manage_data_in_memory() in the example) out into a base class which the 2 classes inherit from.   However, the 2 classes are otherwise not related, and one of them is polymorphic, whereas the other one isn't.   It is also not expected for someone to declare an object of this base class, as it exists only to prevent code duplication (is there a way to enforce this?  I know pure virtual functions can prevent an object from being instantiated, but declaring a dummy pure virtual that does nothing in the derived class seems like bad design).

Does the base class destructor need to be virtual in this case?   This would force the other derived class to also have a virtual destructor, which it doesn't need.
Thanks.

So now I have code in the form

```
class base  {  // don't instantiate an object of this, is there a way to enforce this?
 public: 
   void manage_data_in_memory();
 protected:
    data;        
 };
    
 class derived : public base
 {
 public:
    void sendData();
 private:
     virtual void sendDataHelper(); // override this in derived classes which need to send custom data in addition to the default data
 };
    
 class derived2 : public base
 { 
  public:
   void do_Z_On_data()
 };
```

Comment: Tactical note: Stack Overflow doesn't have threads. A thread implies a discussion, and Stack Overflow deals in questions and answers.

Comment: Inheritance solely to reduce duplication is often the wrong call. Show a simple code example and we'll be able to give good advice on what you should do. Perhaps a free function, maybe in an anonymous namespace to hide it.

Comment: @user4581301 the reason that I didn't use a free function is because it manipulates private data members.

Comment: Those private members could be passed into the function.

Comment: "only some classes are polymorphic" ? are you sure that `do_Z_On_data` is non virtual? There isnt really anything polymorphic in the code you posted

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sorry, I missed the virtual   It should be complete now

Comment: @user4581301 Doesn't that break encapsulation?   Also, isn't one of the reasons for inheritance is to avoid duplicating common code?

Comment: No more than calling `sprintf` on private data to format a string. Willingly handing private data off to a trusted support function is very different from allowing unknown and untrusted code to reach in and manipulate an object's internals.

Comment: One of the reasons, yes, but inheritance implies an [is-a relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) whether you're going to use that relationship or not. You want code that accurately describes the intended result and is-a may not be that description.

Comment: @user4581301 but since manage_data_in_memory() is a public interface function, if it were to become a free function that takes the private data as a parameter, wouldn't that imply the protected data would need to be available to the caller who is external to the class?

Comment: The object's user calls a method exposed by the class's interface the same as they always have. The implementation of the method becomes a one-liner that calls the free function and provides the private data. All of the other classes that are polymorphic do the same thing, call the free function, so the duplicated code is reduced to a function call. The previously duplicated code is tucked away inside the free function.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The destructor of a base class must be virtual if and only if an instance of a derived class will be destroyed through a pointer to the base object. If the destructor isn't virtual in such case, then the behaviour of the program would be undefined. Example:

```
struct Base {
    // ...
};
struct Derived : Base {};


std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr = std::make_unique<Derived>();
// Base::~Base must be virtual
```

It's possible to prevent the user of the class from doing this (at least by accident) by using private inheritance. If the destructor isn't virtual, then inheritance should be private except possibly in special cases where you need a standard layout class.

---

> is this because private inheritance would make the destructor private

No, private inheritance doesn't make destructor private.

> which prevents anyone from declaring an object of Base?

No, and declaring an object of Base isn't a problem.

Private inheritance prevents conversion from derived pointer into a base pointer outside the member functions of the derived class (and friends). The inability acquire a pointer to base of the derived class would prevent the user from deleting a derived object through such pointer.

Comment: is this because private inheritance would make the destructor private, which prevents anyone from declaring an object of Base?

Comment: @ruisen See edit.